# How to get rid of this error it says mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

on my database.php codeigniter

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'employee_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

but on other project is working because i don't have a password on my root account on my phpmyadmin what could be wrong on this one

Comment: Let's read the error message... It says... "Accessed Denied" indicates your database credentials are not correct. And "(Using password: YES )" indicates that you have a password you need to enter in your config for the password...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw that's not what it says. *"Using password: YES"* means that a password was supplied when OP expects their code to **not** use a password

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yup that's what it says but im sure of myphpadmin account is localhost username is just root and doesn't have a password. what's wrong why is asking for a password and just to add i have other projects and it's working fine using just that setting

Comment: @TimBrownlaw So how to change that OP to not expect a password so i can connect?

Comment: Yep my bad! I just did a check and as Phil stated, it does mean it thinks you've supplied a password...I stand corrected, thanks Phil. From your config you are not supplying a password. Might you have another DB config elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @Phil 21 I did check my config.php it doesn't seem to have anything related to connecting on a database and turning off the password

Comment: @TimbrownLaw were in config.php?

Comment: @Lestah Just wondering if you have used $this->load->database('some_other_config) lurking in your code... If you have your password set to anything other than blank (it's set to bank in your database.php) It's seeing a password being set somewhere. That's what I'd be looking for...  Or do you have some 3rd party software in there trying to connect.

Comment: Is this your own application or you trying to integrate some one package. Why I'm asking this because someone will use two database for their application. And there is no need to declare in database.php they can use in controller or model itself. So check the code

Comment: And also check that your hostname is correct or not. Some time it may work with ip address like 127.0.0.1

Comment: @TimBrownlaw nope i did not load any database on my controller and model because i already add this code on my autoload.php $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Comment: @Fairy Dancer this my is my own application what I created this project on my laptop using wamp server and now on my pc desktop i just copy paste the whole application and created the database on my xampp

Comment: In your wamp is its working ?

Comment: @Fairy Dancer yup it's working

Comment: instead  of localhost try using IP of localhost to connect

Comment: awright il using this 127.0.0.1

Comment: nah the same error

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what error message do you get if you change your database username from root to "fluffybunny" or something different. Does that alter the root@localhost part of the error to flufflybunny@localhost.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i did change the username to fluffybunny but it seems like it's doesnt read  that username bec im still getting the root@localhost

Comment: Ah ha! So its not using that particular config... What you think it's reading, it isn't. Now the question is what is it reading... Only you can find that as we don't have access to your files...  Are you looking in the right folder etc... OR are you sure you saved the file...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I dont have any config other than the one i posted on my database.php so im really confused how to find out the right config that should be read

Comment: Where do i need to start looking?

Comment: To add to the mystery it also means that what ever it is using has a password set in it... Seeing as we're in head scratching land here, if you can, create a new project with a clean Codeigniter install and just set up the database and the config and see what that does...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i did create a fresh codeigniter folder test the connection its working when i try to put a wrong username and database name it can detect the error

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i found out what the problem it's now working thanks for your help man how can i be help to you in return

Comment: Well all you have to do is let us all know what the issue was :) and I'll be happy.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i was not on the right application folder it's kind of embarrassing but that's the truth i forgot that i cut my project on a diffrent location and the one that's open on my sublime text editor is the old location on my project that's why when i tried to change the username to fluffybunny and saved it did not work.

Comment: Brilliant :) Don't sweat it,  that's happened to the best of us. Some simple stuff like we did helps you find that kind of stuff :)